# TikZ calendar shading opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, transparency, calendar

When highlighting ranges in a calendar, I can't seem to get the overlapping area to blend as would normally happen with overlapping opaque objects. For example using the following code (compiled with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=2em]
    \draw [line width=5mm, opacity=0.75] (0,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw [line width=5mm, opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- (1,2);
  \end{scope}

  \calendar [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-02-last,
  week list,
  day xshift = 2em,
  day yshift = 2em,
  every day/.style={anchor=center, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em},
  if={(between=2014-02-10 and 2014-02-16)[days={fill=black, text=black, fill opacity=0.75, text opacity=1}]},
  if={(Wednesday) [days={fill=black, text=black, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1}]},
  ];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like the 12 to have the same background fill as the middle of the cross. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used `calendar` and haven't looked at the code, then I don't know how to provide a solution. But I can suggest a workaround.

If you use option `name=mycal` in `\calendar` command every date is a `node` with name `mycal-2014-02-05`. Then it's easy to mark dates after finishing the calendar with something like

```
  \fill[fill opacity=0.5] (mycal-2014-02-05.north west) rectangle (mycal-2014-02-26.south east);
```

to get

[image]

The complete code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=2em]
    \draw [line width=5mm, opacity=0.75] (0,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw [line width=5mm, opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- (1,2);
  \end{scope}

  \calendar [name=mycal, dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-02-last,
  week list,
  day xshift = 2em,
  day yshift = 2em,
  every day/.style={anchor=center, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em},
  if={(between=2014-02-10 and 2014-02-16)[days={fill=black, text=black, fill opacity=0.75, text opacity=1}]},
%  if={(Wednesday) [days={fill=blue, text=black, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1}]},
  ];
  \fill[fill opacity=0.5] (mycal-2014-02-05.north west) rectangle (mycal-2014-02-26.south east); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, just a pity that this issue isn't handled by tikz itself.